# Unlocking and locking protected Worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I have an Excel workbook with many sheets that may lock and unlock programmatically.

`WorkSheet.ProtectContents` did not seem to be updating unless the sheet was activated, so I started throwing this into my functions that use that property.

However, I refactored a bit, and the "for each" loop in the code below quit working if I activate the sheet. My lock and unlock subroutines loop fine with `sheetObj.activate` uncommented.

This does not work and gets stuck on sheet1

```
Public Function getLockStatus() As Boolean
    
    Dim sheetObj As Worksheet
    For Each sheetObj In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        sheetObj.Activate
        Debug.Print sheetObj.Name & ": is locked: " & sheetObj.ProtectContents
        If sheetObj.ProtectContents = False And sheetObj.Name <> "CSV Compatible" Then
            Set sheetObj = Nothing
            getLockStatus = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next sheetObj
    
    Set sheetObj = Nothing
    
    getLockStatus = True
    
End Function
```

but the following code works:

```
Public Function unlockSheets() As Boolean
On Error GoTo doh:

    Dim sheetObj As Worksheet
    For Each sheetObj In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        sheetObj.Activate
        If sheetObj.ProtectContents = True And sheetObj.Name <> "CSV Compatible" Then
            sheetObj.Unprotect Password:="somestring"
        End If
    Next sheetObj
    Set sheetObj = Nothing
    
    unlockSheets = True
    Exit Function

doh:
    Set sheetObj = Nothing
    Debug.Print "Failed to unlock sheets."
    unlockSheets = False
    
End Function
```

Comment: Why are you using `.Activate`?

Comment: `sheetObj` is your loop object, so setting it to `Nothing` inside the loop makes little sense. Not really surprised it doesn't work as you expect.

Comment: your assertion that you must activate a sheet to do stuff with protection is not true. Can you explain what is meant by "This does not work and gets stuck on sheet1"? Are you getting an runtime error? If so, which line is throwing the error?

Comment: I added .Activate to all of these as I had an issue where a user closed out Excel ungracefully.  Whenever they tried to open it back up, Sheet.ProtectedStatus would return false, even though the sheet was actually protected.  In troubleshooting, I activated the sheet, and I noticed it caused the .ProtectedStatus to update.  @braX Crap!  I didn't see that, I think I left it in there when troubleshooting, but removing it does not prevent the loop from getting stuck.

Comment: You may want to update your question then, if the error persists.

Comment: If I let that function run, I'll run out of stack space.  I'm using Debug.print to see that the object is not changing.  As stated, the unlockSheets function works just fine.

Comment: @braX I see what you're talking about now, that `Set sheetOjb = Nothing` is inside of an if statement that breaks the loop, it does not appear to be triggering.  I guess what I'll do for now comment out the `.Activate` but I'm still a bit surprised it should cause an issue.  None of the sheets themselves have any event triggers on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fighting a lion that should be in a cage. Don't think of getting a longer spear. Instead, find out why the cage is left open.

The Protection object has a property `UserInterfaceOnly`. If you create the protection with this property set to True your code can access the sheet without the protection needing to be lifted. The problem is that this property can't be saved. It expires with the current session.

Therefore the protection object should be created with the Workbook_Open event. So, at the Open event remove the protection and set a new protection, 'UserInterfaceOnly = True`, and all the problem you are discussing above won't happen.

Comment: My upvotes don't count yet, but I very much appreciate the help!  Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you for the thumbs-up. You may not have the privilege of voting but you do have the right to accept an answer which, in this case, I think you should do if you followed my advice and it solved your problem.